# lua: piggybacking multiple variables across 1 if statement

Tags: lua

I have around 7+ variables:  a=1, b=10, c=12...etc
I need to write an if statement for each that does this:

```
if var>0 then var-=1 end
```

If I need each of the variables to record their values after each iteration, is there a way for me to avoid writing out one if statement per variable?
I tried defining them all in a table like:

```
a=1;b=2;c=3

local t = {a,b,c}
for _,v in pairs(t) do
    if v>0 then v-=1 end
end
a,b,c=t[1],t[2],t[3]
```

This code failed though, not sure why. Ultimately I'm looking for more efficient way than simply writing the ifs. You can define efficient in terms of cost or tokens or both. The values used would be random, no pattern. The variable names can potentially be changed, i.e. a_1,a_2, a_3, its not ideal though.

Comment: `-=` is not normally available in lua, are you using some specific variant?

Comment: wasn't aware of that, I just meant v=v-1

Comment: you might want to use "print" to help debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions. To shorten your code, you could write a function that processes the value and run it on each variable:

```
local function toward0(var)
  if var > 0 then
    return var - 1
  end
  return var
end

a = toward0(a)
b = toward0(b)
c = toward0(c)
```

You could also store the data in a table instead of in variables. Then you can process them in a loop:

```
local valuesThatNeedToBeDecremented = {a = 1, b = 10, c = 12}

for k, v in pairs(valuesThatNeedToBeDecremented) do
  if v > 0 then
    valuesThatNeedToBeDecremented[k] = v - 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reasign the new values to the table!

```
local a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
local t = {a, b, c}
for k, v in ipairs(t) do
    if v > 0 then v -= 1 end
    t[k] = v
end
a, b, c = t[1], t[2], t[3]
print(a, b, c)
```